# Test JSON reader class with unittest

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, argparse

I wrote a class to read a JSON file, and a method to get a certain parameter from it. The class looks like:

```
import argparse
import os
import json
class JsonReader:
  def __init__(self):
    # define parser and its arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Json reader')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', help='Pass the configuration file in json format', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    # verify the argument is ok (json file)
    if args['config'][-4:] != "json":
        raise Exception(f'Please, choose a json file.')
    if not os.path.exists(args['config']):
        raise Exception(f'The file doesn\'t exists, choose a correct file.')

    with open(args['config']) as json_file:
        self.data = json.load(json_file)

  def get_setting(self, value: str):
    try:
        return self.data[value]
    except:
        raise Exception('"{}" is missing in the configuration file.'.format(value))
```

The class works nicely, but there is an issue when I try to test it with unittest. The test script looks like:

```
import unittest
import os
import sys
from MyFilePath import JsonReader

class TestJsonReader(unittest.TestCase):
    json_reader = JsonReader()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I try to call a script with that class by using:

```
python -m unittest pythonfilename --config "my/path/file.json"
```

I got the following error:

```
usage: python.exe -m unittest [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c] [-b] [-k TESTNAMEPATTERNS] [tests ...]
```

If I don't specify the `--config` argument, I get this output:

```
usage: python.exe -m unittest [-h] -c CONFIG
python.exe -m unittest: error: the following arguments are required: -c/--config
```

Comment: Your script calls `unittest.main()` explicitly; you don't need to use `python -m unittest pythonfilename`, just `python pythonfilename`.

Comment: Thanks Chepner, indeed it works also without using unittest in the terminal line. However, the issue persists.

Comment: `JsonReader` itself should not be processing the command line. You should pass it the name of the JSON file to parse as an argument to `__init__` instead.

Comment: Thanks Chepner, maybe it's just Monday afternoon, but I didn't get it. Could you make an example?

Comment: `unittest` has its own argument parser, which is raising that error.  It doesn't recognize your `--config` flag.  It's quitting before even importing your module.  Providing commandline arguments to both `unittest` and the tested module is tricky, if not impossible.

Comment: uhm, thanks for your answer @hpaulj. That looks annoying :/

Comment: I'd suggest passing a `filename` argument` to `JsonReader`, rather than doing the whole `argparse` step inside the class.  Do the `argparse` stuff in a `if __name__` block, so it is used only when the module is run as a script.  For testing you can do `JsonReader('testfilename'`)` without needing to sneak anything past the `unittest` parser.

Comment: Your own code requires a `--config` option. At the moment, `JsonReader` is doing two things: setting up command line arguments for a CLI and parsing a file. Should these be separate? (hpaulj gives a suggestion if you answer "yes" to this question.)